# Office 365 Enterprise Wiki - Error when clicking on a Category

Tags: managed-metadata, wiki, wiki-pages, office-365, enterprise-wiki

I have created an Enterprise Wiki site in Office 365.

When I click on a "Category" (which is bound to the standard Managed Metadata term set, as standard) I get an error page (Unable to display this web part .. correlation ID .. blah blah blah).

The page throwing the error is */_layouts/15/Categories.aspx* so clearly no chance of getting anything meaningful (this is SharePoint Online / Office 365 here!).

Just wanted to know if this is a known issue? Have you come across this before? Is there a fix?